# Programmatically disable/unregister Excel UDF in C#

Tags: c#, excel, registry, vsto, user-defined-functions

I was wondering, how could we programmatically disable Excel UDF in C#?

I guess perhaps we might have to manipulate registry keys to achieve this. But what subkeys should I be looking at here? I don't want to accidentally destroy the whole subkey tree structure. Can anyone give me some help please?

The registry key structure

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

```
 - CLSID
    - {MYCLASSID}
      - Implemented Categories
      - InprocServer32 **(got quite a few subkeys within, perhaps this one?)**
      - ProgId
      - Programmable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I think I have found the answer myself.

It appears that `(default)` value of subkey **InprocServer32** controls the Excel UDF. If its value is set to **empty**, UDF will not be recognized by the automation server, thus showing #Name mark in the cell, which is pretty much all I need here in this case.

If I want to enable Excel UDF, just set its value to  **C:\WINDOWS\system32\mscoree.dll**, and UDF will be available again.